# mvc validation regexp not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

```
[RegularExpression("/^[a-z,.'-]{2,15}$/i", ErrorMessage = "bla bla'")]
```

I have an input text field regulated with this regexp and for example "asd" should be ok but its not apparently... bla bla is shown!The required data annotation is working propery but this one is not.What am I missing?

Comment: You should only pass a string, not a regex object as string. Use `"^[A-Za-z,.'-]{2,15}$"`

Comment: Very nice placement of the hyphen, BTW. It does not have to be escaped at the end of the character class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only pass a string, not a regex object as string.

```
[RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z,.'-]{2,15}$", ErrorMessage = "bla bla'")]
```

The `/.../` are regex delimiters, and `/i` is a regex case insensitive modifier. This called a regex literal notation in JavaScript. In ASP.NET, you should only pass the *pattern*, the part in between the `/.../` delimiters. Also, you cannot use regex modifiers, but in this case, you can just add `A-Z` to the character class.